# Get data from server only when there is new rows in MySQL table

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I 'm developing an app that collects data from a MySQL server to fill a table . I want to know if there are ways to make the request only if there are new values ​​in the MySQL table.

My intention is to save the data in an array on the phone to not have to collect the data every time you start the app , just make the request to the PHP file if new data exists or have changed .

Thanks , I hope to help someone with the same doubts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a timestamp as a way to check if new data is present on server.

1. Here is the logic.Initially timestamp on device = 0.
2. First Fetch ->  Timestamp on device -> Current timestamp (Code added below).
3. Next App launch -> Send old timestamp to server and get any data after
   that timestamp.
4. Update timestamp on device after each fetch.

Code to save current timestamp on device.

```
NSString * timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];
```

(times 1000 for milliseconds, otherwise, take that out)